# How to use Font Awesome classes on arbitrary tags?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want, very strongly, to avoid littering my markup with non-sematic `<i>` tags and am attempting to use the `icon-*` CSS classes on other elements, such has headers, the primary use case.

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="box-header">
    <h2><i class="icon-list-ul"></i><span class="break"></span>Unordered List</h2>
</div>

<div class="box-header">
    <h2 class="icon-list-ul">Unordered List</h2>
</div>
```

The first is the original markup, the second is my desired markup.  Rendered, they look like:

[image: Initial result.]

I'll worry about the divider later.  Note, however, the difference in 'boldness' of the text.  I notice that Font Awesome by default applies its font (and some other properties) to anything with a CSS class matching `icon-*`, and my first attempt to correct the problem revolved around changing this css:

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    *margin-right: .3em;
}
```

Into the following to ensure the the font selection is only applied to the `:before` icon content:

```
[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    *margin-right: .3em;
}
```

Now I have a different problem, as can be shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Result using modified CSS.]

While the font weight is back to the normal (thin) value, the alignment of the text has shifted down substantially, both for the standard markup and my desired markup cases.  What's going on here, and how can I use the `icon-*` classes on arbitrary elements without those elements own formatting getting out-of-wack?

Thanks for any assistance you can offer!

Comment: So you're against having a separate tag for the icon at all?
ie:
`<h2><span class="icon-list-ul"></span> Unordered List</h2>`

Comment: Yes; a span is even less semantic than an `<i>`.  Presumably the abbreviation of "i" can mean icon, despite its classical interpretation as "italic".  Span is meaningless, but still takes up (needless IMHO) space and adds more code (and thus DOM) to parse, lay out, then render.

Comment: Not sure if you still need help with this but I believe you can use some padding and/or margin on the left to space the text from the icon.

Comment: @MichaelStramel The padding/spacing between icon and text is the least of the problems here.  Any idea how to solve the vertical line alignment issue or solve the font weight issue without messing up vertical positioning?  *Those* are the real issues.

Comment: Aren't icon fonts themselves a gray area when it comes to semantics? I would say that if you wanted to be semantically correct you should just use an <img> tag in the example above. For me that unordered list symbol has a clear meaning and adds value to the text. As such, it's part of the content, not just a pretty decoration.

Comment: @tomasz86 Semantically the icons are irrelevant.  They're visual decoration for the actual heading, which is semantic and if not seen (i.e. by blind users) will not impact use of the site.  Additionally, I'm attempting to explicitly remove the non-semantic markup of <i>, but <img> only adds to the development burden (alt text for accessibility, which is silly as the image does not actually represent "content" in the way it would if the icon were _replacing_ the heading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this has lingered for a long time, I'll post a self-answer [pointing out the methodology I utilize these days](https://gist.github.com/amcgregor/53898a4dcf36082f007d2950deb1f8a3), which involves a SASS/SCSS mix-in.

Basically, follow the methodology of FontAwesome itself, with the exception that instead of populating a bajillion generic CSS classes for use with non-semantic `<i>` (italic) tags, populate the SCSS variables for each character, and dynamically apply via `@include` to the specific elements you wish to have icons applied to.

From the gist example, to automatically apply social media icons to links onto those platforms unless otherwise disabled, you can:

```
a:not(.no-icon) {
    &[href^="https://twitter"],
    &[href^="https://www.twitter"] { @include icon($icon-twitter-square, false, true) { margin: 0; }; }

    &[href^="https://facebook.com"],
    &[href^="https://www.facebook.com"] { @include icon($icon-facebook-square, false, true) { margin: 0; }; }

    &[href^="https://linkedin.com"],
    &[href^="https://www.linkedin.com"] { @include icon($icon-linkedin-square, false, true) { margin: 0; }; }

    &[href^="https://youtube.com"],
    &[href^="https://www.youtube.com"] { @include icon($icon-youtube-square, false, true) { margin: 0; }; }
}
```

Have login / log out links?

```
&[href$="/account/authenticate"] { @include icon($icon-sign-in, false, true) { margin: 0; }; }
```

Want icons defined in the HTML markup? Okay!

```
[data-icon] {
    padding-left: 3.5em;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

    @include icon(attr(data-icon)) {
        margin-left: -3.5em;
        width: 3.5em;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

The difference in boldness comes down to alternate font-smoothing being applied. Forcing `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` and `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale` help to mitigate.

Answer (score -1):

your content inside of `<h2 class="icon-list-ul">` will be affected by the awesomefont setting in `[class*=" icon-"] ...`.
If you want to use different font styles for h2-tags and before-elements,
just keep `[class*=" icon-"]:before` and delete `[class*=" icon-"]`

Comment: I clearly demonstrate an understanding of what you describe within my original question.  Unfortunately the existing `:before` rules do not include such information as the font to use (critical in this instance) which is why I was attempting to re-map the generic rule to the `:before` one, which demonstrated the problems I require assistance with.  (I'll clarify: the problem is specifically why does the apparent amount of bottom padding change when I re-name the rule?  And how can I apply an icon to an arbitrary element without mangling the formatting of that element?)